# Rewriting a jQuery resize function in pure Javascript (codepen included)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble rewriting this jQuery code to pure JS:

```
function scale() {
    $('.outer').each(function () {
        var scaled = $(this),
            parent = scaled.parent().parent(),
            ratio = (parent.width() / scaled.width()),
            padding = scaled.height() * ratio;

        scaled.css({
            'transform': 'translate(-50%,-50%) scale(calc((' + ratio + ') / 1.25)',
        });

        parent.css('height', padding / 1.05); // keeps the parent height in ratio to child resize
    });
}

$(window).resize(function () {
    scale();
});
```

Check out the codepen [here](https://codepen.io/DennisYo/pen/vYYzgMN)

The function scales a div and it's contents proportionally to the window resize.

Comment: Any reason why you want to do that? Is the jquery code inefficient in anyway?

Comment: Not at all no, but I want to include the code in a Stencil.js component and rather don't want to import jQuery for this reason only.